# How to send HTML email with SendGrid Rest API using custom html file with Nodejs handlebars?

Tags: node.js, twilio, handlebars.js, sendgrid

I'm trying to send dynamic emails with Twilio SendGrid Rest API with Nodejs and handlebars. I have created my own custom template and placed the design in a file `template.html`. I'm successfully using this template using Nodemailer and SMTP-transport. But when trying to send it with SendGrid I get error :

> ResponseError: Forbidden
> at node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/classes/client.js:146:29
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {   code: 403,   response: {
> headers: {
> server: 'nginx',
> date: 'Wed, 07 Sep 2022 17:03:16 GMT',
> 'content-type': 'application/json',
> 'content-length': '281',
> connection: 'close',
> 'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
> 'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
> 'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
> 'access-control-max-age': '600',
> 'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
> 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
> },
> body: { errors: [Array] }   } }

**This is my nodejs**

```
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail')
sendgrid.setApiKey(sendgrid_api_key);

//readhtmfile
var readHTMLFile = function (path, callback) {
fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, html) {
if (err) {
throw err;
callback(err);
}
else {
callback(null, html);
}
});
};

//dynamic variable received from client
var name = 'John Doe';

//email user
readHTMLFile(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'template.html'), function (err, html) {
var template = handlebars.compile(html);
var replacements = {
email_title: 'Welcome email',
email_body: 'Welcome to our website '+name
};
var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
var mailOptions = {
from: '"Company Website" <verified_sendgrid_email@company.com>', // sender address
to: email, // list of receivers
subject: "Welcome email ", // Subject line
html: htmlToSend, // html body
};
sendgrid.send(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
if (error) {

console.log(error);

} else {

console.log(response);

}
});
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to log the errors in the `body.errors` array so we can see those?

Comment: @Swimburger : I did and now fixed. Thank you. I believe this answer will help future devs.

Answer (score 1):

Upon printing the body errors, which I should have done, the detailed error was :

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements',
      field: 'from',
      help: null
    }
  ]
}
```

Unlike me, make sure you enter the Verified SendGrid mail. I had misspelled it.

Everything works like a charm now!

If you wonder what the template looks like and how to make it dynamic here it is :

**template.html**

```html
<html>

<head>            

<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.main {
width: 320px !important;
}

.top-image {
width: 20px !important;
}
.inside-footer {
width: 320px !important;
}
table[class="contenttable"] { 
width: 320px !important;
text-align: left !important;
}
td[class="force-col"] {
display: block !important;
}
td[class="rm-col"] {
display: none !important;
}
.mt {
margin-top: 15px !important;
}
*[class].width300 {width: 255px !important;}
*[class].block {display:block !important;}
*[class].blockcol {display:none !important;}
.emailButton{
width: 100% !important;
}

.emailButton a {
display:block !important;
font-size:18px !important;
}

}

.coupon {
border: 5px dotted #bbb;
width: 80%;
border-radius: 15px;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 600px;
}

.container {
padding: 2px 16px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.promo {
background: #ccc;
padding: 3px;
}

.expire {
color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body link="#00a5b5" vlink="#00a5b5" alink="#00a5b5">
<table class="main contenttable" align="center" style="font-weight: normal;border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color: #555559;background-color: white;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;width: 600px;">
<tr>
<td class="border" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid #eeeff0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;">
<table style="font-weight: normal;border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" valign="top" class="image-section" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;background-color: #fff;border-bottom: none !important;">
<a href="https://mycompany.com">
<img class="top-image" 
src="https://mycompany.com/images/webb_logo_.png"
style="line-height: 1;width: 100px;" 
alt="My Company Logo">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" class="side title" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;vertical-align: top;background-color: white;border-top: none;">
<table style="font-weight: normal;border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
<tr style="display: none !important;">
<td class="head-title" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 28px;line-height: 34px;font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">
<div class="mktEditable" id="main_title">

{{{email_title}}}

</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none !important;">
<td class="sub-title" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;padding-top:5px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 18px;line-height: 29px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
<div class="mktEditable" id="intro_title">

{{{email_subtitle}}}


</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="top-padding" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 5px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="grey-block" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;background-color: #fff; text-align:center;">
<div class="mktEditable" id="cta">
<img class="top-image"
src="https://mycompany.com/images/learn.gif"
style="width:100% !important;" />
<br><br>

<a style="color:#000067; 
background-color:#FCE8ED;  
border: 10px solid #FCE8ED; 
border-radius: 3px; 
text-decoration:none;" href="https://mycompany.com/login.php">
Log In Your Account Now
</a>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="top-padding" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 15px 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 21px;">
<hr size="1" color="#eeeff0">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;">
<div class="mktEditable" id="main_text">

{{{email_body}}}


<br><br>
<span style="font-style: italic;">
<small>
<strong>
    “ Build powerful and beautiful websites in 5 mins or less without coding ”
</strong>
</small>

</span>

</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;">
&nbsp;<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="text" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;">
<div class="mktEditable" id="download_button" style="text-align: center;">

</div>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px; padding: 20px;">
<div class="mktEditable" id="cta_try">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile" style="font-weight: normal;border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
<tr>
<td class="rm-col" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;padding-right: 15px;"></td>
<td class="force-col" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;">
<table class="mb mt" style="font-weight: normal;border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top: 0;">
<tr>
<td class="grey-block" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 18px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;background-color: #fff; border-top: 3px solid #00a5b5; border-left: 1px solid #E6E6E6; border-right: 1px solid #E6E6E6; border-bottom: 1px solid #E6E6E6; width: 250px; text-align: center;">

<span style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
font-size: 24px; 
line-height: 39px; 
border-collapse: collapse;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
color: #555559; 
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;">
Need Help?
</span>
<br>
My Company team is here to support you. 
Visit our Help Center.<br><br>


<a style="color:#ffffff; 
background-color: #00a5b5;  
border-top: 10px solid #00a5b5; 
border-bottom: 10px solid #00a5b5; 
border-left: 20px solid #00a5b5; 
border-right: 20px solid #00a5b5; 
border-radius: 3px; 
text-decoration:none;" 
href="http://mycompany.com/contact.php">
Contact Us
</a>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>   
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>                                           
<tr bgcolor="#fff" style="border-top: 4px solid #00a5b5;">
<td valign="top" class="footer" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;line-height: 26px;background: #fff;text-align: center;">
<table style="font-weight: normal;border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">
<tr>
<td class="inside-footer" align="center" valign="middle" style="border-collapse: collapse;border: 0;margin: 0;padding: 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;color: #555559;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 12px;line-height: 16px;vertical-align: middle;text-align: center;width: 580px;">
<div id="address" class="mktEditable">
<b>
My Company Inc
<br>
Tech Support : 24/7/365
</b><br>
<a style="color: #00a5b5;" 
href="https://mycompany.com">
Visit our website
</a>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```